# Creating a automata where the length of the 0's in the automata are odd

Tags: finite-automata, automata, state-machine

Is this possible to create with a finite state machine?

So like 101 is accepted because odd number of 0's
but 1001 is rejected because even 0's

11 is not accepted because 0 is even.

etc etc.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and it's easy to do it with only two states representing even number of 0's and odd number of 0's respectively:

[image]

The accepted state is 2

Comment: Yes it works: you read 1 => State 1 then 011 => State 2 then 0 => State 1, 0 => State 2 and 01 => State 1. Your word is rejected because it has an even number of zeros.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, I may haven't explained it well, it needs to have an odd number of zeroes  so like 10110001 works because there is an odd number of zeroes incased in the first 1 and an odd number of zeroes incased in the second ones.